# Scalling in 5.1 Hera

Tags: release-hera, scaling

I would like to make my interface scaling 125%
Please let me know how to do this correctly, completely and permenantly.

I saw a few posts on using xrandr, but I tried that and it did not work.
Likewise gconf editor.

Just a little bit too small for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the standard eOS settings panel go to "Desktop"

Go to "Appearance"

Select "Large" for text size.

Comment: Can you accept your answer in order to be visible that the question is resolved?